# Two-sided market framework

Tags: microeconomics, industrial-organisation, networks

I have a very basic question about the elasticity of demand/participation in the two-sided market framework, as created by [Weyl (2010)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.100.4.1642) and described by [Jullien, Pavan, and Rysman (2021)](https://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/apa522/Two-Sided-Market-and-Network-Effects.pdf). Using the notation of Jullien et al., let $q_i$ be the participation rate on side $i$. The intermediary/platform sets a price $P_i$ for a side $i$ agent to participate. An agent on side $i$ pulls a type $(v_i,\theta_i)$ from some bivariate, twice-continuously differentiable distribution with pdf $f_i(v_i, \theta_i)$. Here $v_i$ represents the utility the agent gets from participating and $\gamma_i$ represents a sort of interaction benefit the agent gets from participation on the other side (which is denoted $q_j$).

So, the utility for an agent on side $i$ is:

$u_i(v_i, \gamma_i, q_j) := v_i + \gamma_iq_j$

And the participation on side $i$ is:

$D_i(P_i,q_j) := q_i = \text{Pr}(v_i + \gamma_i q_j > P_j)$

It appears to me that $\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial P_i} = -1$, but this outcome feels so strong and isn't directly stated in the literature (as far as I know), so I'm left with doubts. The reasoning is as follows:

Participation on side $i$ is:

$D_i(P_i, q_j) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{P_j-\gamma_iq_j}^\infty f_i(v_i,\gamma_i)d v_id\gamma_i$

So, using Leibniz rule and the FTOC:

$\frac{\partial D_i}{\partial P_i} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_i(v_i = P_j-\gamma_iq_j,\gamma_i) d \gamma_i = -1$

What is wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 2):

I made a very elementary error in forgetting that $f_i(v_i=P_j-\gamma_iq_j,\gamma_i) = f_i(\gamma_i|v_i=P_j-\gamma_iq_j)\text{Pr}(v_i=P_j-\gamma_iq_j)$. This is not the same as $f_i(\gamma_i|v_i=P_j-\gamma_iq_j)$. So the correction amounts to:

$$\frac{\partial D_i}{\partial P_i}=\text{Pr}(v_i=P_j-\gamma_iq_j)$$

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than a fully fledged answer. But my sense is that you should consider the effect of $P_i$ on $q_j$, as well (see Rochet and Tirole (2006, RAND)).

Minor notes:

1. the condition is $v_i + \gamma_i q_j > P_i$ (not $v_i + \gamma_i q_j > P_j$)
2. In the Jullien et al. paper $\theta_i = (v_i, \gamma_i)$ (not $(v_i,\theta_i)$)